# Tikzmark and Forest package is not working in XeLaTeX?

Tags: forest, tikzmark

See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    [\subnode{15}{15}\ 18
        [\subnode{13}{\phantom{13}}]
        [\subnode{16}{16}\ 17]
        [19]
    ]
\end{forest}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[->] (15) to[out=180,in=90] (13);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces, using `pdfLaTeX`
[image: functioning]

Compiling now the same under `XeLaTeX` yields

[image: not working]

Comment: use lualatex instead of xelatex.

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike. :)

Comment: btw: the problem is independant of fontspec, xelatex gets something wrong here.

Comment: Oh, in fact! My IDE just did automatically switch to pdfLaTeX when I removed the usepackage to `fontspec`. I will edit this in the question. Thanks!